# How to update the webpart control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts

I have changed the appearnce of one of the control of webpart of my site. 
But when user opens the web page user finds the old apperance of that webpart control.
However when user adds new webpart instance, new changed webpart control gets appear.
So how I need to dispaly the new appearance of the webpart when user opens the page.
Kindly reply.

Answer (score 0):

See following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhy9ewf1.aspx)

I hope it will help you to understand how to update the webpart control in asp.net.

Comment: Hi, thnks for your reply. 
The above link did not solve my problem